# Is it possible to do Data Driven Testing using SAPb1 Testcomposer?

Tags: sapb1

Is it possible to do data driven testing using SAPb1 Test Composer automation tool instead of changing the scripts every time for new updation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not supported.

1) you can use the custom operation to read from the Excel sheet the data and use it in the script;

2) The script are nothing more than XML files so you can create a tool to reproduce that XML and change the necessary data;

3) Get the source code for Test Composer and change it to take into account an excel sheet with data.